# Serverside configuration constants in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I need some configuration files, that can be changed without recompiling the project in my GWT application. However, the GWT i18n doesn't allow to be used serverside.

So what's the solution for getting configuration constants to be used serverside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need them on the server side then go with the standard **java.util.Properties** class. If you want to share constants between both then create an additional RPC service call to get the list of properties to your client.

Comment: But java.util.Properties require a crazy amount of code for doing extremly simple things. I somewhat assumed GWT had a "smarter" solution for it, since it have a smart solution for clientside constants.

Comment: Also it seems it's completely GUESSWORK where the relative paths of Java starts when deployed in a WAR archive, gaaaaaaah -.-

Comment: I agree but GWT code is client side and it's optimized for that. You might find some other library which suits your needs. I have written the code for this ages ago and still use it.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the GWT i18n interfaces working on the server side is easy with a [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html).

1. Our team put the GWT i18n properties
   files in the same location as the
   `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages`
   classes they generate. They are then
   deployed in the same directory as
   the class files, somewhere under
   /classes, and are therefore on the
   webapp's classpath.
2. Read in the [`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) from the deployed properties file. With the previous step, finding the properties file is easy: it's the name of the GWT i18n interface.
3. `Proxy` the GWT i18n interface on
   the server side and use the proxy's
   `InvocationHandler` to look up the
   right property in the
   `ResourceBundle`. Finding the right property is also easy: it's the name of the invoking `Method`.

You now have GWT i18n interfaces created on the server. You can edit the properties file and redeploy without recompiling. However the changed constants won't be picked up on the client side.